# Equivalent of SQL IN in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, comparison-operators

What I am trying to do is to check if a value matches one of two numbers (and easily be able to add to the numbers to compare to). Rather than doing a longer-winded way such as:

```
If Number = 1 Or Number = 2 Then ...
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
If Number In (1,2) Then...
```

As the `In` operator isn't available in VB, I have tried the following code instead:

```
Protected SectionID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("sectionid")
Protected PageID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("pageid")

Protected Sub HotspotsLV_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles HotspotsLV.ItemDataBound
    Dim SecondLineHolder As HtmlControl = e.Item.FindControl("SecondLineHolder")
    Select Case True
        Case New String("2", "3").Contains(SectionID) : SecondLineHolder.Attributes("style") = "color:#21720B"
        Case New String("8", "12").Contains(PageID) : SecondLineHolder.Attributes("style") = "color:#1B45C2"
    End Select
End Sub
```

I have found that this only works when `SectionID` is 2 or `PageID` is 8. If `SectionID` is 3 or `PageID` is 12 then it doesn't work. Why is this and what can I do to try to get around the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of playing around, I have managed to find a nice solution:

```
Select Case True
    Case Array.IndexOf(New Integer() {2, 3}, SectionID) > -1 : SecondLineHolder.Attributes("style") = "color:#21720B"
    Case Array.IndexOf(New Integer() {8, 12}, PageID) > -1 : SecondLineHolder.Attributes("style") = "color:#1B45C2"
End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim Numbers() As Integer = {1, 2}
If Numbers.Any(Function(i) i = Number) Then
```

Comment: Thanks - I have also tried this but I get the error "'Any' is not a member of 'System.Array'".

Comment: You need at least .NET Framework 3.5 and a reference to the Linq library. Joel, why not use Contains?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a `String` instance not an array. Try changing it to:

```
Protected SectionID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("sectionid")
Protected PageID As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("pageid")

Protected Sub HotspotsLV_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles HotspotsLV.ItemDataBound
    Dim SecondLineHolder As HtmlControl = e.Item.FindControl("SecondLineHolder")
    Dim sections As Integer() = New Integer(){2,3}
    Dim pages As Integer() = New Integer(){8,12}
    Select Case True
        Case sections.Contains(SectionID) : SecondLineHolder.Attributes("style") = "color:#21720B"
        Case pages.Contains(PageID) : SecondLineHolder.Attributes("style") = "color:#1B45C2"
    End Select
End Sub
```

If you use `Option Strict On` then the type mismatch would be highlighted. In your initial code `New String("2", "3")` would create a string with a value of `222`.

### Edit

For .Net version prior to 3.5 the `Contains` method will not be available. This can be mimicked using `IndexOf`:

```
Array.IndexOf(sections, SectionID) > -1
' Equivalent to sections.Contains(SectionID)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - however I get the error "'Contains' is not a member of 'System.Array'" using this method.

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using? `Contains` is an extension method avaiable from version 3.5. I've included an edited for versions prior to this.

Comment: That's strange because the website I'm working on is in verson 3.5!

Comment: Wierd - does `Contains` show in intellisense? I assume that it doesn't.

Comment: No it doesn't for Array objects, although it does for ArrayLists.